# Javascript wildcard in IF statement using Datalayer

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how I can use a wildcard in below statement for a Facebook pixel implementation:

```
if (_satellite.getVar('dlPageName') === "main:education:future_of_light") {
fbq('init', '123456789');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
}
```

dlPageName refers to the main blog overview page. But all blogs beneath it need to be included as well. So for instance if dlPageName is main:education:future_of_light:education is should also fire the fbq events. What is best practice here? Cause not sure how to use regex in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression:

```
if (/^main:education:.*$/.test(_satellite.getVar('dlPageName'))) {
    fbq('init', '123456789');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
}
```

This is just an example, but `/^main:education:.*$/` will match any string that begins with `^main:education:`, the `.*$` part is not strictly necessary, but you can build from there.

You can read more about RegExp [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) and test your own using [this tool](https://regexr.com/).

Answer (score 0):

With regex and/or match

```
if (_satellite.getVar('dlPageName').match("main:education:future_of_light")) {
```